# index_col parameter in datatable fread function

Tags: python, pandas, datatable

I want to accomplish the same result as:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col=0)
```

But in a faster way, using the **datatable** library in python and convert it to a pandas dataframe. This is what I am currently doing:

```
import datatable as dt
datatable = dt.fread("data.csv")
dataframe = datatable.to_pandas().set_index('C0')
```

Is there any faster way to do it?

I would like to have a parameter that allows me to use a column as the row labels of the DataTable: Like the `index_col=0` in `pandas.read_csv()`. Also, why does `datatable.fread` create a 'CO' column?

Comment: Can you convert to a DataFrame and then call set_index()?

Comment: @cs95 Yes, I have tried that and it works, I have updated my question. The problem is that at the end is the same speed as just doing `pd.read_csv("data.csv")`.

Comment: In all likelihood it isn't possible, this module doesn't even have any decent documentation about its usage. Looking at the source code and the method definition, I don't see any way of setting the index during read time. Sorry about that.